# How to automatically export (and download) a chart made with Highcharts in Angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts, export, angular-highcharts

I work in an Angular project. I built a chart with the Highcharts library and the [Angular-Highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts) package.
The chart is well displayed.
The following step is to export automatically the chart by using the Highcharts [exportChart](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart%23exportChart#exportChart) method but it does not work. I did many tries but often got the error :

> Property exportChart does not exists on type 'Chart'

I suppose the `exportChart` method native to the Highcharts library does not completely fit to the adaptation needed to make the chart work on Angular. But is there a trick to use that snippet in Angular to automatically download the chart ?

```
    this.chart.exportChart({
      type: 'application/pdf',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
  });
```

Here is my work on that StackBlitz :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-example-d1qdsv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Could you check it and help me on that problem ?  Any help would ve very appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the mentioned error as you are using the `Chart` instance which is from 'angular-highcharts' library.

And in this class, there is no `exportChart` method.

Would recommend using the 'highcharts' library instead.

```js
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

(Highcharts.chart('chart', /* chart options */)).exportChart({
  type: 'application/pdf',
  filename: 'my-pdf',
});
```

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-example-51e4ay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)